# would like to combine rows of two dataframe where they have same value with panda. since my column header are different its not merging

Tags: python, pandas

where value of countyFIPS of df1 = value of FIPS of df2 merge the rows
**df1**

```
countyFIPS  feb    march  
1001          aa    45
1002          bb     1
```

**df2**

```
FIPS   dec    nov   
1001    ee    45
1002    gf     1
```

I want the result show like

```
countyFIPS      feb    march   dec    nov 
    1001          aa    45       ee    45
    1002          bb     1       gf     1
```

Answer (score 1):

`df.merge(df2, left_on='countyFIPS', right_on='FIPS', how='inner').drop(columns=['FIPS'])`.

But before this I would like you to take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101). This post already teaches everything required for merging.

Comment: So countyFIPS and FIPS are not is same order. i dont just cant to join them. they have to compare the value and rearrange in the new dataframe

Comment: You can sort them and then join/merge them.

Comment: You can use `df.sort_values(by=['col'])`. See the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) as below:

```
df1.join(df2, how='left').drop(['FIPS'],axis=1)
```